# XAML: How do I make part of a GroupBox Header bold, with binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, header, styles, groupbox

I've asked a question long ago and got help on it. The requirement has changed slightly.

Original question:
[XAML: How do I make part of a GroupBox Header bold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270164/xaml-how-do-i-make-part-of-a-groupbox-header-bold)

The original requirement was to just hard-code the header text to:

**Students** (Max: 32)

The solution that Ed gave me was:

```
<GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock>
        <Span FontWeight="Bold">Students</Span>
        <Span>(Max: 32)</Span>
    </TextBlock>
</GroupBox.Header>
```

Now I need to bind both of these sections to some dependency properties, such that the header would appear as one of these:

- **Students** (Max: 32)
- **Students** (Max: 64)
- **Employees** (Max: 32)
- **Employees** (Max: 64)
- etc...

I need to have binding to both of these Span sections, something akin to this:

```
<GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock>
        <Span FontWeight="Bold">{Binding ProfessionString}</Span>
        <Span>{Binding MaxString}</Span>
    </TextBlock>
</GroupBox.Header>
```

, but obviously the {Binding ProfessionString} and {Binding MaxString} will be displayed verbatim.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Could just do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365567/multiple-colors-in-textblock/11852742#11852742)

Comment: Once I understood both answers I realized that this one was similar to mm8's answer. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Run` elements and bind their Text properties to your source properties:

```
<GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding ProfessionString, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Run Text="{Binding MaxString, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </TextBlock>
</GroupBox.Header>
```

Comment: Made it look easy. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

How about two TextBlocks:

```
<GroupBox.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding ProfessionString}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaxString}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox.Header>
```

Comment: Thank you. It was really hard picking the preferred answer. This one helps me better visualize the structure.